# How to upload product images with custom sort order in magento?

Tags: magento, sorting, magento-1.7, uploader

I am working in magento 1.7 version.

I created a module similar to product for upload images.

This is using flash uploader as product uses for upload images.

But when I upload the multiple images then they set random sort order.

**Example** 
when I upload 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg images.
Then there sort order will be

Image | sort order

1.jpg  | 2

2.jpg | 1

3.jpg | 3

**But it should be**

Image | sort order

1.jpg | 1

2.jpg | 2

3.jpg | 3

How can I change sort order to newly uploaded files.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can sort your productimages, when product has been saved ( use product save after event )
and then sort the productimages in your on way.
You can find the sortorder of the productimages in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value ( magento 1.8, 1.7 should be the same ).

cheers

Comment: I need to change sort order before showing images to grid.Like First I browse the images.Then when I click on upload, images should shows in grid with my custom order.not after save the product.

Comment: i see.
When using flexuploader, magento returns an json string, that contains e.g. the url of the uploaded image or filesize, after pressing "Upload Files".
Then the flexbridge is called in the file ..\js\mage\adminhtml\flexuploader.js.
In that file you find several functions, i think you have to modify updateFiles or updateFile function in the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Manu for your answer.I got the some events due to file upload process handles but  still not able to find how they add sort order for images.It will be great help if you give me some more guidance  regarding this.I looked whole flexuploader.js and image.phtml  and its controller file but no luck :(

Comment: Hi, 

i haven't implemented this already, but i've done some debugging for you.
You have to look in file flexuploader.js for the function handleComplete, should be about on line 169.
At the end of this function, you have to write your own functionality to sort the html-table.
The id of that table is "media_gallery_content_grid" then you have to work with prototype on the tr elements ( e.g. media_gallery_content-image-0 etc ) and sort them 
in the way you want.